# How to restrict Horizontal Lines with Timeframe Range in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

My Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lot_size = 3750
min_vol = 60
path = 'C:\\Data\\ONGC19FEBFUT.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=",")
df.columns = ['Date','Time','Price','volume']
df['Volume'] = np.where((df.volume/lot_size) < min_vol, 0, (df.volume/lot_size))
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df.plot(x="Time",y='Price', rot=0, color='g')

plt.title("Date: " + str(df['Date'].iloc[0]))

dff = df[df.Volume > min_vol].reset_index(drop=True)
dff = dff[['Time','Price','Volume']]
print(dff)

dict = dff.to_dict('index')
for x in range(0, len(dict)):
    plt.axhline(y=dict[x]['Price'],linewidth=1, color='blue')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.06, right=0.95, top=0.96, wspace=None, hspace=None)
plt.show()
```

My Current Output:
[image: Output]

Dataframe **dff** gives the price values to be plotted over the chart. I want to segregate the prices values to be plotted as per 30 min duration i.e. Price Values from 09:00 to 09:30 to be plotted within the time range, Price Values from 09:30 to 10:00 to be plotted within this timeframe and so on.
I want to restrict the Horizontal Price Lines for every 30 min time frame.

**dff Output:**

```
                 Time  Price    Volume
0 2019-02-15 09:15:02  132.90   111.0
1 2019-02-15 09:15:03  134.15    78.0
2 2019-02-15 11:14:46  132.65    68.0
3 2019-02-15 11:27:24  131.95    73.0
4 2019-02-15 12:40:36  129.50   176.0
5 2019-02-15 13:42:52  129.90    75.0
6 2019-02-15 13:52:26  130.05    71.0
7 2019-02-15 13:52:40  129.70    99.0
```

My Desired Output:
[image: Desired]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

lot_size = 3750
min_vol = 60
path = 'ONGC19FEBFUT.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=",")
df.columns = ['Date','Time','Price','volume']
df['Volume'] = np.where((df.volume/lot_size) < min_vol, 0, (df.volume/lot_size))
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

pic = df.plot(x="Time",y='Price', rot=0, color='g')
pic.margins(0.0)

plt.title("Date: " + str(df['Date'].iloc[0]))

dff = df[df.Volume > min_vol].reset_index(drop=True)
dff = dff[['Time','Price','Volume']]
print(dff)

dict = dff.to_dict('index')

# get the 30-min interval in which x resides
def get_interval(x):
    y, m, d = x.year, x.month, x.day
    if x.minute < 30:
        hours = (x.hour, x.hour)
        minute = (0,30)
    else:
        hours = (x.hour, x.hour+1)
        minute = (30,0)
    return datetime(y, m, d, hours[0], minute[0], 0), datetime(y, m, d, hours[1], minute[1], 0)

start = df["Time"][0]
end = df["Time"][df["Time"].size-1]

# get the position of x in x-axis
def normalize(x):
    return (x-start)/(end-start)

for x in range(0, len(dict)):
    interval = get_interval(dict[x]["Time"])
    xmin, xmax = list(map(normalize, interval))
    plt.axhline(y=dict[x]['Price'], xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, linewidth=1, color='blue')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.06, right=0.95, top=0.96, wspace=None, hspace=None)
plt.show()
```

There are the two arguments `xmin` and `xmax` for the function `plt.axhline`.
And they can only accept a floating number between 0 and 1. So there is a `normalize` function above.

Comment: Thanks Sir for the nice explanation. I want to write the volume values above the horizontal lines. is it possible..?

Comment: Try this: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Comment: Sir the time interval for row **5 2019-02-15 12:40:36  129.50   176.0** is showing wrong **(datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 15, 12, 30), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 15, 12, 0))**. it should be 13 *(datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 15, 12, 30), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 15, **13**, 0))*

Comment: The Function **def normalize(x): return (x-start)/(end-start) & xmin, xmax = list(map(normalize, interval))** doesnot return the right location of Time Frame. Like I want to plot the line exactly plotted between 09:00 to 09:30, 09:30 to 10:00, 10:00 to 10:30 so on.

Comment: That's because the pandas add margin to the picture, so the line looks shifted to left.

Comment: Yes the Lines are somewhat Ok near 12:00:00 but shifted a lot in both extreme.